# Scroll Eye Tracking using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make something like Samsung Galaxy S4's Eye Scroll (although eye is in the name; but it is actually head I believe) for a web app using JavaScript. I get the input video stream using `getUserMedia()` but I don't really know where I can from here... I have looked at

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-motion-detection.html
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/head-tracking-with-webrtc/

But it doesn't seems like I can actually track my head (up and down) using any of these. Also, I don't want to use OpenCV contact the Python server and etc... I just want some real time tracking of head on the webpage then doing something from it. If I get any idea how I can do with JavaScript nicely, I'll get going...

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/head-tracking-with-webrtc/ and http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/03/12/move-a-cube-with-your-head/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you are after is in one of the above links. The functionality you are after can pretty easily be implemented using [headtrackr.js](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/).

This javascript library will let you detect and then track the head in 2d (faceTracking Event) or in estimated 3d (from the headTracking Event).

To get started, just download [headtrackr.js](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/raw/master/headtrackr.js) and include it in your project:

```
<script src="js/headtrackr.js"></script>
```

and the following code will initiate a headtrackr with a video element (the mediastream) and a canvas element that the frames will be copied to (good for debugging)

```
<canvas id="inputCanvas" width="320" height="240" style="display:none"></canvas>
<video id="inputVideo" autoplay loop></video>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var videoInput = document.getElementById('inputVideo');
  var canvasInput = document.getElementById('inputCanvas');

  var htracker = new headtrackr.Tracker();
  htracker.init(videoInput, canvasInput);
  htracker.start();
</script>
```